# Populate custom drupal form in colorbox/lightbox/popup

Tags: forms

I have a drupal custom form and a table attached to form. So when we create a new entry using form, that entry is now shown in table with an EDIT LINK. I want to use a  form populated in colorbox/lightbox/popup when click on EDIT LINK for edit selected entry.

how can i achieve this using any module/custom ?

Comment: concept is that when click on link, it send some id to target page (like /edit-details?q=123). On the basis of id, i make some calculation and then create form fields (populated). Also these fields are dynamic i.e. number of field depend on ID passed with clink on link. Help me...